# Exchange 2010 sp 3 instalation - failed Organization Checks Prerequisites

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2010, service-pack, prerequisites

After command

```
Setup.com /M:Upgrade /InstallWindowsComponents
```

Failed on Organization check

```
Welcome to Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 Unattended Setup
Preparing Exchange Setup
Copying Setup Files                           COMPLETED
The following server roles will be upgraded
Languages
Hub Transport Role
Client Access Role
Mailbox Role
Management Tools
Performing Microsoft Exchange Server Prerequisite Check
    Configuring Prerequisites                                 COMPLETED
    Organization Checks                                       FAILED
Cannot find at least one domain controller running Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 or later in domain 'DC=xxx,DC=local'.
```

This could be the result of moving domain controller objects in Active Directory. Check that at least one domain controller running Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 or later is located in the 'Domain Controllers' organizational unit (OU) and rerun setup.

2 Domain controlers i OU 'Domain Controllers' (on MS server 2016)

Comment: Yeah. So, what did you try? You are capable of reading - the error message is pretty clear.

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: 2 x DC on 2k16 servers, 2 x exchange server 2010 (1x hub transport+ca+mailbox, ver sp2 on 2k8r2, 1 x edge transport sp1 on 2k8r2).

Comment: Yeah. And did you read the error message and did you do what is written there as fix?

Comment: both of DC server are in 'Domain Controllers'. Maybe the system does not recognize new servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exchange 2010 does not support Windows Server 2016 Active Directory servers. Re-setup an Windows server 2012 R2 or previous Windows server, then check the result.

Also, if it is a new organization, it's best to re-setup the domain environment, then install Exchange 2010 server.

See: [Exchange Server Supportability Matrix](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff728623(v=exchg.150).aspx)

Comment: Exchange server is on 2k12r2. But new DC servers on 2k16. Maybe i need to turn on one controller on 2k12r2. Current domain functional level is 2k12r2.

Comment: this is not a problem with the installation of a new/additional exchange server, only with  installing service pack 3 on an existing server.

Comment: Actually, according to the TechNet guidance, Exchange 2010 SP3 CU5 and later does not support Win2012R2. It does not support Windows Server 2016 Active Directory servers either.  I suppose you installed Exchange 2010 servers and removed the original DC before you installed Windows 2016 Active Directory servers.  Even the Exchange 2010 server runs on Win2012R2, it's not the best practice. If any problems happens, Microsoft may refuse to provide support such scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I added an additional (third) DC on 2k12r2 and ... success! Thank you very much for your answer!

```
G:\temp_exchange_sp3>setup /prepareAD

Welcome to Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 Unattended Setup

Setup will continue momentarily, unless you press any key and cancel the installation. By continuing the installation
process, you agree to the license terms of Microsoft Exchange Server 2010.
If you don't accept these license terms, please cancel the installation. To review the license terms, please go to
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=150127&clcid=0x409/

Press any key to cancel setup................
No key presses were detected.  Setup will continue.
Preparing Exchange Setup

    Copying Setup Files                           COMPLETED

No server roles will be installed

Performing Microsoft Exchange Server Prerequisite Check

    Organization Checks                                                                               COMPLETED

Configuring Microsoft Exchange Server

    Organization Preparation                                                                          COMPLETED

The Microsoft Exchange Server setup operation completed successfully.
```

Comment: do I understand you right that you only had to add another DC on 2012 Server? no real migration of FSMO and stuff?